# Why are unauthorized users able to access my REST API even though I'm using 'IsAuthenticated'?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

So here is a function in my views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@csrf_exempt
@authentication_classes(BasicAuthentication)
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def UserAPI(request):
    userlist = MyProfile.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(userlist, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now if I go to this URL, it shows me all the user information despite not being logged in.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  I'm assuming I don't need to set DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in my settings since I'm using the decorators.

Comment: does it work if you change api_view decorator to api_view('GET') and place the authentication_classes + permission_classes decorator below the csrf_exempt and api_view decorator?

Comment: Try swapping the order of the decorators, so that `api_view` is above `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes`.

Comment: I swapped them, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: have you check it in incognito broswe, or just via CURL from Terminal? Maybe you have some cached session in web browser.

Comment: I tried curl, same thing.

Comment: Is the authentication middleware in place ? (Check settings.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a syntax error there: for the authentication_classes you should send an iterable, not a single element. Could you try with the following code:

```python
@api_view(['GET'])
# @csrf_exempt     # you should be safe without this on a GET method
@authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication, ))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def UserAPI(request):
    userlist = MyProfile.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(userlist, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, also I didn't need the authentication middleware.

Comment: Side question, is it normal my browser pops up a windows requesting user name and password?  I assumed I would just automatically get a forbidden error in the browser (unless I was logged in)

Comment: Yeah... it is... For the basic authentication. The browser does recognise this scheme and tries (and succeeds) to prepare the authorisation header. Normally at the front-end you would fire up a mechanism which will request the user for his password and then attempt to make the AJAX call. The browser will inspect an AJAX with a valid authorisation header so it will allow the call.